# Twitter Bootstrap add active class to li in Master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the twitter bootstrap navbar and I want the active class to change when I go to another page but it just stays on the home page.
Here is the html on the master page

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size: medium; color: white;">
        <li class="active"><a href="Index.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Connect.aspx">Connect</a></li>
        <li><a href="Develop.aspx">Develop</a></li>
        <li><a href="MarketPlace.aspx">Marketplace</a></li>
        <li>
            <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome&nbsp;<asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
                    &nbsp;
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
            <asp:LoginStatus runat="server"></asp:LoginStatus>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I found an answer that said to use this

```
$('.navbar li').click(function (e) {
    $('.navbar li.active').removeClass('active');
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But I tried it and it doesn't work. I have the js files in there

```
<script src="jquery/src/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/offcanvas.js"></script>
```

And the relevant css files are there but it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: how do you load your another page, via ajax or via loading the full page?

Comment: Loading the full page. When I click on a link in the navbar I want the active class to change to the current page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't use ajax to load page when clicking to link. If It is so, the problem is that after you set 'active' class, the page reloads and it is all new. You need to decide which li will be active in your backend code or detect in javascript, what page are you currently in.

UPD:

The javascript method would look something like that

```
if (location.pathname.match(/connect.aspx/i)) $('a[href="Connect.aspx"]').parent().addClass('active')
if (location.pathname.match(/develop.aspx/i)) $('a[href="Develop.aspx"]').parent().addClass('active')
```

etc.
But this is kludge pretty much.
The better solution would be adding `class="active"` to needed `<li>` when generating page. But I don't know how your pages are generated so I cannot show example. If you use just different html files, just edit them so different `<li>`s have `active` class. If you use template engine, or something else, use its methods.

Comment: Ok do you know where I could see some sample code that will do that?

Comment: I use different html files but I use a master page to hold the code relating to the <li> element and active class

Comment: @Ronan then you need to add server-side logic in your master-page. sorry I dont know ASP so I cannot help you there

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by overriding the bootstrap dropdown-menu class in my CSS file:

```
.dropdown-menu > li.active > a {
    background: white !important;
    color: black !important;
}

.dropdown-menu > li.active > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li.active > a:focus {
    background: $navbar !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```